# Zend Framewotk 2 Installation (needs help)

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Hello i want to install zend framework 2 on my box. I am following this link -- http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html. when i use

```
 E:\Nisarg\ZendSkeletonApplication>php composer.phar create-project --repository-
url="http://packages.zendframework.com" zendframework/zendframework  c:\wamp\www
\zc
```

It show me the error that shown below

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]

  The "http://packages.zendframework.com/packages.json" file could not be dow
  nloaded: failed to open stream: Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" -
   did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?
```

tell me where am i goes wrong?

Comment: The core is going to be `Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" -
   did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enable SSL in PHP fsockopen()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494376/enable-ssl-in-php-fsockopen)

Comment: how can i do enable ssl?

Answer (score 1):

You are on Windows, so you should be able to activate SSL by uncommenting the line that includes

```
php_openssl.dll
```

Comment: Did you restart the server?

Comment: http://www.nemesis.co.nz/2013/05/composer-and-wamp-unable-to-find-the-socket-transport-ssl/ Check this link if you have WAMP, it worked for me, since I had to enable extension=php_openssl.dll in both php.ini files, one in C:\wamp\bin\apache\ApacheYourVersion\bin\php.ini and the other is in C:\wamp\bin\php\phpYourVersion\php.ini then restart WAMP and you can use Composer

Answer (score 0):

You have to uncomment the `extension=php_openssl.dll` in `path_to_wamp\bin\apache\Apache-version\bin\php.ini` and `path_to_wamp\bin\php\php-version\php.ini` and restart WAMP.